# Browser back button does not work with asp controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a site with few asp:CheckBoxList and asp:DropDownList controls. Checking few options or selecting few items in the dropdowns makes the back button browse to same page just with previous selections. I would like the back button on the browser take the user to the previous website visited. As example: if the last visited site was: default.aspx, then the back button from my current site should go back to default.aspx. 
Adding few header options regarding caching only broke the back button to: Page Not Found message.

How can the user browse back to the default.aspx by the first back button clicked on the browser?

Comment: If you have the attribute "AutoPostBack" set to true in the CheckBoxes this is the expected behavior. Do you have any code behind handling  the CheckBoxes clicks?

Comment: My advice would be to get away from ASP.Net Forms as it is plagued by these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to confirm, are u using IE 10 to run the web system?

I had encounter asp control component not working properly when i was using IE 10.

Maybe consider using other browser type like firefox and safari to see if it can work properly